# swift regex get certaint substrings in string

Tags: swift, regex

I have a string like this one and i want to get the text after src= to the end of .m3u8.

Example:

```
let string = "loremipsum-src=https://loremipsum.m3u8&pano-src=https://loremimpum.m3u8&proj"
```

I want to get the substrings `https://loremipsum.m3u8`

This is what I am trying for now:

```
let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "src=(.*?).m3u8", options: .caseInsensitive)
if let match = regex.firstMatch(in: string, range: NSRange(NSRange(string.index(string.startIndex, offsetBy: 4)..., in: string)) {
    
    let substring = string[Range(match.range(at: 1), in: string)!]
    
}
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to get multiple occurrences of that URL after `src=`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes but i called regex.matches instead of firstMatch

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
let string = "loremipsum-src=https://loremipsum.m3u8&pano-src=https://loremimpum.m3u8&proj"

let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "src=(https://.*?.m3u8)", options: .caseInsensitive)
if let match = regex.firstMatch(in: string, range: NSRange(string.startIndex..., in: string)) {
  let range = match.range(at: 1)
  let output = (string as NSString).substring(with: range)
  print(output) // // https://loremipsum.m3u8
}
```

ps - if u user your pattern as `"src=(.*?.m3u8)"`(changed the bracket) it will also work.

---

without using NS Classes

```
let pattern = "src=(https://.*?.m3u8)"

if let range = string.range(of: pattern, options: .regularExpression, range: string.startIndex..<string.endIndex, locale: nil) {
    let extractedString = String(string[range])
    let output = extractedString.replacingOccurrences(of: "src=", with: "")
    print(output)
}
```

Comment: Why all of the non-Swift classes? Swift provides regex handling without the need for NSString, NSRange, or even NSRegularExpression.

Comment: @HangarRash no need. There are many ways to get the desired output. What I did was fixing the error in the code mentioned in the question.